# Getting HTML includes to work with XAMPP

Tags: html5, xampp

I am having problems getting a virtual host to display includes. I am using XAMPP for Linux. I have tried "XBitHack on", which didn't work.

My index.html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://shamar.org/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="verify-v1" content="jILCms9UBQLGa4vAPY5nmhxTzW8kRj12iXnxrg7zWIU=">
    <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="E553571C6477AC566A8C74B52925BFDB">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>shamar.org</title>

        <!-- start CSS Area -->
    <!--#include virtual="includes/css.html" -->
        <!-- End CSS Area -->

    <script src="/js/daily_scripture.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body class="wv-disable">
      <header>
        <!--#include virtual="/includes/upperNavShamar.html" -->
      </header>

      <div class="site-main-container">

        <!-- Start latest-post Area -->
        <section class="latest-post-area pb-120" style="padding-top:10px;">
          <div class="container no-padding">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 post-list">

          <!--   Begin Daily Script   -->
          <!--   <div class="dailyScript">   -->
          <div class="dailyScripture">
          <script>
          <!--
            writeTip();
          -->
          </script>
          </div>
          <!--   End Daily Script   -->
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-8 post-list">
            <!-- Start latest-post Area -->
            <div class="latest-post-wrap single-sidebar-widget">

  <!--#include virtual="/includes/frontPageShamar.html" -->

  <!-- End latest-post Area -->
    </div>


  <!--#include virtual="/includes/rightColumnShamarHome.html" -->

    </div>

  <!-- start footer Area -->
    <!--#include virtual="/includes/footerShamar.html" -->
  <!-- End footer Area -->

  <!-- start JavaScript Area -->
    <!--#include virtual="/includes/javascript.html" -->
  <!-- End JavaScript Area -->

</body>
</html>
```

My .htaccess (that which may pertain to this):

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
# Use +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch instead of +FollowSymLinks option for security
RewriteEngine On
ServerSignature Off
Options +Includes

AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType application/epub+zip .epub
AddType application/x-mobipocket-ebook .mobi
AddType text/html .html .htm
AddHandler server-parsed .html
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html .shtml
```

The domain-related section from http-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/home/lee/htdocs/shamarNew/"
  ServerName shamar.test
</VirtualHost>
```

I have several other virtual domains that work fine, except those are all .php files where here they are all .html. I know HTML does allow includes as it works on my web host. BTW, it does display the non-included text. The example above only show the Scripture JavaScript but nothing else.

Any suggestions? If other files are needed just let me know.

Comment: Presumably you aren't getting any errors output? So, the directive would not seem to be processed at all. You shouldn't need the `AddHandler server-parsed .html` directive (that's for old versions of Apache AFAIK). If you rename your file with a `.shtml` extension, does it work? To clarify, this file `index.html` is in the document root directory (ie. `/home/lee/htdocs/shamarNew/index.html`?

Comment: No errors.

I removed the "AddHandler"

I tried renaming an include with .shtml, but that didn't work.

index.html is in the document root directory

Comment: "I tried renaming an include with .shtml" - To clarify, the file in which you have the SSI would need to have the `.shtml` extension, not the file you are including. ie. `index.shtml`. Is `mod_include` enabled? Restarted Apache?

Comment: "the SSI would need to have the .shtml extension". Tried it but didn't work. mod_include is enabled. Apache restarted each time there is a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in the vhost file. Error I received: `"Expected </VirtualHost> but saw </Directory>"`. Deleted the `</Directory>`, replaced it with `</VirtualHost>`. Everything seems to work fine now. (But I do feel stupid.)

I appreciate all your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   DocumentRoot "/home/lee/htdocs/shamarNew/"
>   ServerName shamar.test
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

Your vHost is very minimal? You will need to allow `.htaccess` overrides in the server config, otherwise your `.htaccess` is simply going to be ignored (or at least some of the directives). You also need to allow access to the document root - although I assume you must be doing this somewhere already otherwise your site would not be accessible.

For example, inside your vHost container:

```
<Directory "/home/lee/htdocs/shamarNew/">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

...and restart Apache.

Also, this is only the vHost for port 80 (HTTP), so I assume you are only referencing this over plain HTTP, not HTTPS. (Although you reference HTTPS in the HTML.)

Comment: Yes, I am referencing "http".

I already have that in my server config file. Remember, this works for all the ".php" files, just not for ".html" includes.

Comment: IN RE ABOVE: While these includes have a .html extension, the ones for the .php have an "inc" extension, if that makes a difference.

Comment: "this works for all the ".php" files" - I kinda assumed you would be using PHP `include()` inside PHP files? If you are using SSI for PHP files, did you try enabling `.html` for that vHost? Same result?

Comment: "While these includes have a .html extension, the ones for the .php have an "inc" extension" - that shouldn't be a problem. You can have _nested_ includes. But it is worth testing that. Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I have tried the .inc extension but it didn't work. Here is a change in the top of my .htaccess file: # Options +Includes
Options +ExecCGI +Includes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes

Comment: I don't think it really makes sense to include both `+Includes` and `+IncludesNOEXEC` (I would expect the later to take priority). You don't need two `Options` directives.

Comment: Right. I'll remove the +IncludesNOEXEC. The first Option has a # in front of it. It's the existing line.

Comment: This is in my error log for XAMPP: "mod_include: Options +Includes (or IncludesNoExec) wasn't set, INCLUDES filter removed: /index.html" But I have set it in the conf file and the .htaccess file.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be the "file extension", but this particular VirtualHost? That error would seem to suggest there is another `Options` directive that is perhaps overriding the directives you are setting? You might be able to determine this by increasing the `LogLevel` in the server config and check the output.